# .Net Core Access Response From Custom Middleware Before Serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on a custom middlware that's going to set the response Http Status Code based on the response itself.

I have a class:

```
public class Response<T>
{
     public T Data { get; set; }
     
     public IEnumerable<CustomError> Errors { get; set; }
}
```

that is returned by every controller in my .Net Core API.

I want to create a custom middleware that's going to access the response after it is returned from the controller and it will assign a correct Http Status Code in the Response based on the `Errors` field.

I can see some solutions for accessing the `Response.Body` field of the `HttpContext`, but it would provide a serialized string that I would have to deserialize again and that's running around in circles.

Is it possible in .Net Core?

Best regards,
Marcin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of middleware, you could create an `ActionFilter`, specifically your own implementation `IAsyncResultFilter`. It's going to be easier to cast to `Response` in the MVC context rather than in the middleware because you may access there `ObjectResult`.

It could look like this.

```
public class Response
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Errors { get; set; }
}

public class Response<T> : Response
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

Note that I changed the `Response<T>` class to make casting easier.

```
public class ErrorResultFilter : IAsyncResultFilter
{
    public Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext context, ResultExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var result = context.Result as ObjectResult;
        var response = result?.Value as Response;
        if (response != null)
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode
                = response.Errors.Any(x => x.Equals("SomeError")) ? 400 : 200;
        return next();
    }
}
```

This sample sets status code based on the presence of `"SomeError"`. There's no serialization/deserialization involved, just casting.

```
services.AddControllers(o => 
{
    o.Filters.Add(typeof(ErrorResultFilter));
});
```

This way, I registered my filter in the `startup.cs`